# assertEquals(string, string) comparisonFailure expected: <str[]> but was: <str[ ]>

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4, assertions

I reversed a string using StringTokenizer and written this code under reverseToken(str) method. I was testing using junit4

```
@Test  
public void testReverseToken(){  

    assertEquals(new String("rev this"), Calculation.reverseWord("ver siht"));  
}
```

Why I am getting `junit.comaprisonFailure` as:

```
comparisonFailure expected: <str[]> but was: <str[ ]>
```

What is this `str[]` and `str[ ]` *(having space)*

Comment: The code you posted should not give that output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is not produced by the test code you posted. It simply says that the test expected the string `"str"`, but got `"str "` instead (i.e. there is an additional space at the end of the string that should not be there).

Comment: I second...but that is what I got in Failure Trace